# How to change the button text of MS Dialog Pop-up?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog, popup

I have an event calender. When people add events to it, a workflow is started automatically. When they click add a pop-up appears. I want to change the button text from "Save" to "Request". How can it be done?

NewForm.aspx Code

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListFormPageTitle runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span class="die">
    <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="LinkTitle" runat="server" id="ID_LinkTitle"/>: </span>
    <SharePoint:ListItemProperty id="ID_ItemProperty" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server" >
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="ms-quicklaunchouter">
                <div class="ms-quickLaunch">
                <Sharepoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="4">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <h2 style="display:inline;" class="ms-hidden"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></h2>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><label class="ms-hidden"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></label>
                        <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="ViewFormPages">
                            <div class="ms-quicklaunchheader"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton id="idNavLinkViewAll" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/></div>
                        </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
                        </h3>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                <Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager
                id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"
                runat="server"
                QuickLaunchControlId="QuickLaunchMenu"
                ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
                EnableViewState="false"
                CssClass="ms-quicklaunch-navmgr"
                >
                <div>
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server"
                        ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
                     <Template_Controls>
                        <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                        SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                        ShowStartingNode="False"
                        id="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                        StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025"
                        runat="server"
                        />
                     </Template_Controls>
                    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
            <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <SharePoint:AspMenu
                        id="QuickLaunchMenu"
                        runat="server"
                        DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                        ItemWrap="true"
                        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                        StaticSubMenuIndent="0"
                        SkipLinkText=""
                        CssClass="s4-die"
                        >
                        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="ms-navheader"/>
                            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="ms-navitem"/>
                        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
                        <LevelSubMenuStyles>
                            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="ms-navSubMenu1"/>
                            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="ms-navSubMenu2"/>
                        </LevelSubMenuStyles>
                        <LevelSelectedStyles>
                            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="ms-selectednavheader"/>
                            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="ms-selectednav"/>
                        </LevelSelectedStyles>
                    </SharePoint:AspMenu>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
            <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <SharePoint:AspMenu
                      id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                      runat="server"
                      EnableViewState="false"
                      DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                      UseSimpleRendering="true"
                      Orientation="Vertical"
                      StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                      MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                      SkipLinkText=""
                      CssClass="s4-ql" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                </div>
                </Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager>
            <Sharepoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="3">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager
                    id="TreeViewNavigationManager"
                    runat="server"
                    ContainedControl="TreeView"
                    >
                      <table class="ms-navSubMenu1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <table class="ms-navheader" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td nowrap="nowrap" id="idSiteHierarchy">
                                  <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchy" Text="<%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <div class="ms-treeviewouter">
                        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TreeViewAndDataSource">
                          <Template_Controls>
                            <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl
                             runat="server"
                             id="TreeViewDataSource"
                             RootContextObject="Web"
                             IncludeDiscussionFolders="true"
                            />
                            <SharePoint:SPRememberScroll runat="server" id="TreeViewRememberScroll" onscroll="javascript:_spRecordScrollPositions(this);" style="overflow: auto;height: 400px;width: 150px; ">
                              <Sharepoint:SPTreeView
                                id="WebTreeView"
                                runat="server"
                                ShowLines="false"
                                DataSourceId="TreeViewDataSource"
                                ExpandDepth="0"
                                SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tvselected"
                                NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-navitem"
                                NodeStyle-HorizontalPadding="2"
                                SkipLinkText=""
                                NodeIndent="12"
                                ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvplus.gif"
                                CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvminus.gif"
                                NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvblank.gif"
                              >
                              </Sharepoint:SPTreeView>
                            </Sharepoint:SPRememberScroll>
                          </Template_Controls>
                        </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                      </div>
                    </Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
            <Sharepoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="4">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager
                    id="TreeViewNavigationManagerV4"
                    runat="server"
                    ContainedControl="TreeView"
                    CssClass="s4-treeView"
                    >
                      <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" Text="<%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>" CssClass="s4-qlheader" />
                          <div class="ms-treeviewouter">
                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TreeViewAndDataSource">
                              <Template_Controls>
                                <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl
                                 runat="server"
                                 id="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                 RootContextObject="Web"
                                 IncludeDiscussionFolders="true"
                                />
                                <SharePoint:SPRememberScroll runat="server" id="TreeViewRememberScrollV4" onscroll="javascript:_spRecordScrollPositions(this);" style="overflow: auto;height: 400px;width: 155px; ">
                                  <Sharepoint:SPTreeView
                                    id="WebTreeViewV4"
                                    runat="server"
                                    ShowLines="false"
                                    DataSourceId="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                    ExpandDepth="0"
                                    SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tvselected"
                                    NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-navitem"
                                    SkipLinkText=""
                                    NodeIndent="12"
                                    ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvclosed.png"
                                    ExpandImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/images/tvclosedrtl.png"
                                    CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvopen.png"
                                    CollapseImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/images/tvopenrtl.png"
                                    NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/images/tvblank.gif"
                                  >
                                  </Sharepoint:SPTreeView>
                                </Sharepoint:SPRememberScroll>
                              </Template_Controls>
                            </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                          </div>
                    </Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server" id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV3">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="s4-die">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr><td>
                        <table class="ms-recyclebin" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr><td nowrap="nowrap">
                        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/recyclebin.aspx" id="v3idNavLinkRecycleBin" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/recycbin.gif" Text="<%$Resources:wss,StsDefault_RecycleBin%>" PermissionsString="DeleteListItems" />
                        </td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server" id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <ul class="s4-specialNavLinkList">
                            <li>
                                <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                                    runat="server"
                                    NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/recyclebin.aspx"
                                    ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
                                    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                                    ImageWidth=16
                                    ImageHeight=16
                                    OffsetX=0
                                    OffsetY=428
                                    id="idNavLinkRecycleBin"
                                    Text="<%$Resources:wss,StsDefault_RecycleBin%>"
                                    CssClass="s4-rcycl"
                                    PermissionsString="DeleteListItems" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                                    id="idNavLinkViewAllV4"
                                    runat="server"
                                    PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                                    NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                                    ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
                                    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                                    ImageWidth=16
                                    ImageHeight=16
                                    OffsetX=0
                                    OffsetY=0
                                    Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_short%>"
                                    accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                </div>
                </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div style="padding-left:5px">
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="onetIDListForm" style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td>
     <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{26C3C970-8387-4248-A20F-BCC54765A91F}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Travel Request for CC</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <Description />
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge />
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_26c3c970_8387_4248_a20f_bcc54765a91f</ID>
  <ListName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{4650F9F9-D7D2-4ECC-B2F2-E0EFFC995DA5}</ListName>
  <ListId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">4650f9f9-d7d2-4ecc-b2f2-e0effc995da5</ListId>
  <PageType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">PAGE_NEWFORM</PageType>
  <FormType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">8</FormType>
  <ControlMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">New</ControlMode>
  <ViewFlag xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">1048576</ViewFlag>
  <ViewFlags xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">Default</ViewFlags>
  <ListItemId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">0</ListItemId>
</WebPart>
</WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart>
</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
     <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='590' height='1' alt="" />
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td class="ms-areaseparatorleft"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
    if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
}
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorleft'><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are actually referring to the standard NewForm.aspx which is however shown in a pop-up (code usually adds IsDlg=1 in the Query string to enable automtic removal of extra content in page). It should be enough to customize the actual form via SharePoint Designer and replace the button value with your own, which very easily you could locate in the form in a table containing ms-toolbar CSS class.

One quick example http://www.risetime.com/knowledgecenter/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6, but you should be able to find more if you are looking for ways to customize list forms in SharePoint.

A word of caution: While customizing the form, the default ListView available in the page cannot be changed, DO NOT DELETE that, but rather choose to Hide it (WP properties), add another one and that will give you total freedom of change.

Comment: Now I am editing NewForm.aspx but I am not able to find any table with css class with ms-toolbar. Where is the button "Save"?

Comment: try finding <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton1" RedirectUrl="somePageToGo"/> and replace with <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://myotherpage}')}" />

Comment: I couldn't find it. I added the full Code of NewForm.aspx.

Comment: It makes sense you couldn't find it because only the default ListView is present. In my answer i mentioned to Hide the Default list view and Insert a new Web Part  which you would afterwards customize. Please follow the steps properly or you shall find yourself breaking the list functionality.